# calling a double from object seems to return the possition not value of the double

Tags: kotlin

In a function i have this:

```kotlin
val sunRise = SunEquation(2459622)
binding.timeDisplay.setText("$sunRise.n")
```

The SunEquation-Class looks like this:

```
class SunEquation(var jDate: Int,) {

    val jYear = 2451545
    val ttOffset = .0008

    var n = jDate - jYear + ttOffset
}
```

the button- text that appears is:

```
com.example.soluna.SunEquation@6d1a94b.n
```

i would expect a double-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add curly brackets around the value you want to inject into the String, like this:

```kotlin
binding.timeDisplay.setText("${sunRise.n}")
```

The shorthand syntax without brackets only works for a single variable, but not
for access to a nested field or other more complex expressions.

In your case, this results in the object itself being injected into the String, which is resembled by `com.example.soluna.SunEquation@6d1a94b` based on the result of the corresponding `toString()` call, which defaults to the class name and the reference id of the object. Followed by the literal String `.n`.

Alternatively, you could extract the value into a `val` beforehand and reference that.

```kotlin
val customN = sunRise.n
binding.timeDisplay.setText("$customN")
```

Comment: Just a small correction: those are braces, not parentheses

Comment: Mmm. Round these parts, `()` are ‘parentheses’, ‘round brackets’, or just plain ‘brackets’; `[]` are ‘square brackets’; `{}` are ‘braces’ or ‘curly brackets’; and `<>` are ‘angle brackets’ (or ‘less than’ and ‘greater than’).

Comment: Thanks, I adjusted the text accordingly.